# CSS and JS can't load in a html from bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to load a layout((https://bbbootstrap.com/snippets/multi-step-form-wizard-30467045#add-comment) but my efforts are turning unsuccessful.

```
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!--font -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>

     <!-- Custom stlylesheet -->
    <link href= "signup.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" >
</head>

    </div>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <link rel="icon" href="signup.js">
</body>
```

The code above shows the links for the template, the Stylesheet and JavaScript. I really don't know what I am missing that would cause it not to reflect.

Comment: You're using `script` tag to add css files, use `link` tag instead

Comment: FYI, the basic structure is `<html><head>...</head><body>...</body></html>`

Answer (score 1):

For CSS, you should use `<link rel="stylesheet">(...)</link>` instead of `<script>` tag

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can notice,
there is no starting `<body>` tag or starting `<div>` tag.
Maybe you copy-pasted it wrong, please look into it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Head section sould be something like

```
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!--font -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

     <!-- Custom stlylesheet -->
    <link href= "signup.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" >
</head>
```